# Como desativar as indicações (gutter) do Git de linhas modificadas no VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Toda vez que eu estou programando, tenho dificuldade com uma anotação da extensão Git Lens no VSCode. O problema é que quando eu desejo recolher linhas de código — clicando naquela seta para baixo — eu acabo clicando sem querer nesses botões das indicações que abrem uma janela e isso me atrapalha muito.

Aqui está uma foto ilustrando:

[image: Exemplificação do Gutter no VisualStudio Code]

Como eu desabilito essas barras verdes?

Comment: Leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas) e leia também [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta?cb=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é um indicador do status do Git — ou qualquer software de controle de versão suportado. Nesse lugar, é chamado de *gutter*, que é a indicação à esquerda das linhas de código.

Para desativar, você pode utilizar a configuração *"SCM: Diff Decorations"*:

```
"scm.diffDecorations": "all" | "gutter" | "overview" | "minimap" | "none"
```

Se você quiser remover qualquer tipo de indicação, defina como `none`. Se você quiser remover somente a indicação no *gutter*, defina como `overview` ou `minimap`.

Se você definir como `overview`, as indicações aparecerão somente numa barra vertical na direta do editor, próxima à barra do *scroll* vertical. Se você definir como `minimap`, as indicações aparecerão somente no *minimap*, se este estiver habilitado.

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Muito obrigado Luiz Felipe :D